# Require Lua files from writeable path

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

I'm currently stuck with this problem for about 3 days now.

I'm using cocos2d-x 2.1.3 and Lua scripting for the game.
Using `AssetsManager` as a base, I have now successfully fetched `.zip` files from server and load them in the app. However, there's a tiny catch.

In my project (which is based on `AssetsManagerTest`), it downloads a `.zip` file (called `package.zip` containing two files, a `.png` (called `HelloWorld.png`) and a `.lua` file (called `game.lua`). The `.lua` file simply creates a `HelloWorld` scene, just to test if it works, and it did.

Then I edited `game.lua` file to require another `.lua` file, called `gem.lua`. When I try to run it, it reports an error saying that it cannot find `gem.lua`. So I tried editing my `C++` code to make use of `CCLuaEngine::addSearchPath( const char * )`, however, it still doesn't work.

I download `package.zip` folder and extract it into the path returned by `CCFileUtils::getWritablePath()`. The files are properly extracted and the `game.lua` is found. When I tried adding `gem.lua` into the package, I added this bit of code:

```
// Obtain the full script path. The value returned is:
//     CCFileUtils::getWritablePath() + "/games/game/scripts"
const std::string scriptPath = MyAssetManager::sharedManager() -> getScriptPath();

// Obtain the script file path
std::string gamePath = scriptPath + "/game.lua";

// Add the scriptPath to the LuaEngine search paths
CCLuaEngine::defaultEngine() -> addSearchPath( scriptPath.c_str() );

// Run the script
CCLuaEnging::defaultEngine() -> executeScriptFile( gamePath.c_str() );
```

Even though `gem.lua` is in the proper path (`/games/game/scripts/`), the engine can't somehow find it. After looking around, it turns out the base path for the search paths is the `Resource` folder.

Is there a way to make the `CCLuaEngine` look for the writable path? It can be done with resources, though.

This is the whole error message I get:

```
[LUA ERROR] ...D35-DB7A1B515ED3/Documents/games/game/scripts/game.lua:3: module 'gem.lua' not found:
    no field package.preload['gem.lua']gem.lua
    no file './gem/lua.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/luajit-2.0.1/gem/lua.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/gem/lua.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/gem/lua/init.lua'
    no file 'Scripts/gem/lua.lua'
    no file 'Scripts/Common/gem/lua.lua'
    no file 'Scripts/HomeScene/gem/lua.lua'
    no file 'Scripts/Games/gem/lua.lua'
    no file '/Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/E0CFD097-5DED-4E6D-8D35-DB7A1B515ED3/Documents/games/game/scripts/gem/lua.lua'
    no file './gem/lua.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/gem/lua.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
    no file './gem.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/gem.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

Comment: What is the error message you get? (The one that says it cannot find `gem.lua`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the error message you probably wrote something like `require "gem.lua"` in your code. You should remove the extension: `require "gem"`.

Comment: This fixed the error above but cocos2d-x still wasn't able to find it. I solved it by adding the scripts folder to the resources search paths, not the lua search paths. Thanks!